# Google Analytics API doesn't give full results for certain catalogs

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, powerbi, google-analytics-firebase

We use the google analytics core reporting API for our dashboards (GA plugin in power BI application).
What we need is the transactionid and the default channel grouping. This is working well for two of our websites.

But we have an issue with one website - Both Reporting and Raw Data which does not retreive the transaction ids with the corresponding default channel grouping. However, when doing a manual export from google analytics from acquisition channels by adding transactionid as a secondary dimension, we get the right information. We do not understand what is causing this misalignment.

**Dimensions Chosen: Date, Default Channel Grouping and Transactionid
Metrics: Transactions, Revenue and Sessions(optional)**

I get the correct number of transactions, but the issue happens when I try to combine more than one dimension(transactionid + default channel grouping).

Can you please some advice or suggest in going about getting the right information from ?
It is confusing when it works for two websites and there is 80% transactionid missing from the third website.